# How to access Print dialog's 'Open PDF in Preview' in os x programmatically

Tags: macos, delphi, pdf, print-preview

I am building a **Delphi** application which opens an image and its metadata and prints it. For the Windows version I build a form to generate the PrintPreview, but in Mac I can use the **Print Dialog**'s **'Open PDF in Preview'** instead. When I click on it, a PDF file is generated and I can see it, its OK. The problem is I want to access this option directly from a button, so when the button is clicked, the PDF in Preview is opened and the user does not have to open the Print Dialog, then click the 'PDF' and then select 'Open PDF in Preview'. How can I do this?

I read about using Automator, apple scripts etc, but I still can't find it. 
Is there any path this generated PDF Preview is stored, so maybe I can open it from there?...

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Using Automator or Applescript or both to recursively print documents to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822487/using-automator-or-applescript-or-both-to-recursively-print-documents-to-pdf) but I'll answer anyways.

To answer your question directly see the question I linked to. Basically you need to use System Events from applescript to accomplish that exactly

---

However, there's a quicker solution using `/usr/sbin/cupsfilter`. Check the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/cupsfilter.8.html) for more.

You can call `cupsfilter <an-image-file>` and you'll get a PDF on stdout, courtesy of OSX's printing daemon. It looks quite configurable but I just learned about it a while ago.

If you want this to open for the user you can save it in a nice place or you can do it the one-shot way and do `cupsfilter <your-image> | open -f -a "Preview"` to open the PDF right up.

Comment: I am a complete newbie in applescript and Automator so I firstly checked the **cupsfilter** solution. It worked fine, I managed to open up the PDF, but the problem is all I get is the image, instead of all the page I want to send to the printer, so that includes even metadatas. I created this page using the FMX.Printer in Delphi, which means this does not exist as a file anywhere so I can not access it and using then **cupsfilter**. That why I wanted to access the file generated by OS X itself in PDF--> Open PDF in Preview. Thanks a lot for your help!!